# How to Overwrite ActionController::RoutingError on Rails application to catch "bad Ip"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have daily bad request than generates a lot of logs in production.log like this:

```
F, [2016-02-08T15:39:17.698761 #2437] FATAL -- : 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/sites/default/files/elsevier/eop/S0025-7753(12)00231-X.pdf"):
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call...'
```

In my website there isn't a route for  /sites/`: this is a foreign webservice error, and  I want to know its IP to solve the problem.

I have learned this, but doesn't work and I think I need something else of code

(I have Rails 4.0.2 and I will upgrade to 4.2.5 soon.)

1- In `routes.rb`, at the end:

```
 match '*path', :to => 'application#routing_error', via: :all
```

2- In `application_ontroller`: I log the IP and then **I need to render the 404.html if I'm on production or render the rails error normaly if I'm on development**

```
  def routing_error(error = 'Routing error', status = :not_found, exception=nil)
    logger.debug { "---> I catch you #{request.remote_ip}" }
    render status: 404, file: "404.html"
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

in routes.rb

```
class RoutingErrorConstrain
  def initialize
    @prodenv = Rails.env == "production"
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @prodenv
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do

...
  match '*path', to: 'application#render_routing_error',
                 via: :all,
                 constraints: RoutingErrorConstrain.new
...
end
```

in application_controller.rb:

```
  def render_routing_error
    logger.warn do "
        BAD IP: #{request.ip}. Remote_ip: #{request.remote_ip}"
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
        { render file: "public/404.html", layout: false }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: status }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `application_controller` simply write below code -

```
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: lambda { |exception| render_error(404, exception) }

def render_error(status, exception)
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { render template: "public/#{status}", layout: false, status: status }
     format.all { render nothing: true, status: status }
   end
end
```

You can put a condition in a method to check rails environment.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I'm testing it on development and it doesn't work...¿? I've put a ´byebug´ before ´respond_to ..´ and the ´render_error´ method is not executed

Comment: Definitely is not executed on development, I've been reading Rails guides where I can find more examples like yours, testing it in different ways... without success

Comment: this will never be run since ActionController::RoutingError is thrown at the routing stage before a request is dispatched to any controller.